# Missing a temporary folder problem while image upload

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-5

showing 'Missing a temporary folder.' problem

added below code in wp-config.php file

define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(**FILE**) . '/wp-content/temp/');
also Created the Temp Folder inside wp-content

define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(**FILE**) . '/wp-content/temp/');

Missing a temporary folder

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include more information about your hosting environment. This could also be a permissions issue.

Comment: I m using vps server with vestacp panel

Comment: Who is the VPS Server with? Google, AWS, Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste this code to the file just before the line that says ‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging’.

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/');
```

Save your changes and upload the wp-config.php file back to your website.

**Next,** you need to go to /wp-content/ folder and create a new folder inside it. You need to name this new folder temp.

**Note:** **If this method doesn’t work, then check the [directory permissions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/) for your wp-content folder.**

Comment: I have make All changes as u said but still not working

Comment: @user3601901 Please check you Uploading Files settings Under tab Settings >> Media .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cause of your issue is that whatever plugin/theme is using the upload process, is not using the WP temp directory, it's using the PHP upload temp directory.

Try adding a temp directory for php uploads using these steps:

1. Edit the php.ini file, usually `/etc/php/{version num}/apache2/php.ini`
2. Find the line that reads `upload_tmp_dir` and uncomment it (remove the semi-colon at the front of the line)
3. Edit the line to read `upload_tmp_dir = "/var/temp"`
4. Create the temp folder if it doesn't exist `mkdir /var/temp`
5. Make sure that the folder owner is www-data, like `chown -R www-data:root /var/temp`
6. Make sure the folder permissions are set to 775 at most, like `chmod -R 775 /var/temp`
7. Try uploading an image again to your WP instance

This may fix your root issue, although this response is rather delayed from your post, so maybe you already found something.